# Filter vs Partition in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to find nonzero element in the given array and move zeros to the back. Applying filter approach it works. Applying partition approach gives me array is not mutable issue.

I wonder advantages of using filter and partition in terms of time complexity and as well as space complexity. Usually which is preferably used?

```
var inputArray = [1,4,0,0,5,1,0]
```

**Filter Approach**

```
func NonZeroArrayWithFilter(array:[Int]) -> [Int] {
  return array.filter({$0 > 0}) + array.filter({$0 == 0})
}
```

**Partition Approach**

```
func NonZeroArrayWithPartition(array:[Int]) -> [Int] {
  return array.partition(by: { $0 > 0 }) + array.partition(by: { $0 == 0 })
}
```

Comment: In *Partition Approach*  array is immutable, and the return value isn't an array, it is the index of the first element in the reordered collection that satisfies the condition

Comment: Unclear what the intended output is. You have not stated that order among the nonzeros should be preserved, and indeed, your own second approach does not preserve it. Is that a desideratum or not?

Answer (score 1):

`filter` returns an array of elements that matched your condition; `partition` reorders the array such that all elements that match your condition are before the ones that don't. For instance:

```
var array = [1, 5, 2, 6]
array.filter { $0 < 4 } // returns [1, 2]

// reorders `array` to [1, 2, 5, 6], and returns 2:
// all elements before array[2] are smaller than 4
array.partition { $0 < 4 }
```

In other words, `partition` does not return a new array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short solution:

```
array.sorted { $1 == 0 * $0 }
```

It is *O(n log n)*. It IS short, but not as quick as *O(2 n)* of your *Filter Approach*.

A more efficient solution would be:

```
func zeroTail(_ array:[Int]) -> [Int] {
    guard !array.isEmpty else { return array }

    var tempo = Array(repeating: 0, count: array.count)
    var index = 0
    array.forEach { element in
        if element != 0 {
            tempo[index] = element
            index += 1
        }
    }
    return tempo
}

zeroTail([0,1,2,0,6,0,2,5,0])  //[1, 2, 6, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

It traverses the array only once: *O(n)*.

`partition` is efficient, but it's not suitable here because it swaps elements that [`belong in the second partition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017527-partition), with others that don't. And that contradicts the requirement of keeping the original order of the non-zero elements.

---

You could also define an extension on Array in general:

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {
    func withTail(_ value: Element) -> [Element] {
        guard !self.isEmpty else { return self }

        var tempo: [Element] = Array(repeating: value, count: self.count)
        var index: Int = 0
        self.forEach { element in
            if element != value {
                tempo[index] = element
                index += 1
            }
        }
        return tempo
    }
}
```

And here are some use cases:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 6, 0, 2, 5, 0].withTail(0)            //[1, 2, 6, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
["c", "a", "c", "b", "c", "d", "c"].withTail("c")  //["a", "b", "d", "c", "c", "c", "c"]
[1.2, 2.3, 4.5, 1.2].withTail(6.0)                 //[1.2, 2.3, 4.5, 1.2] 
[Character]().withTail("a")                        //[]
```

Comment: I've never had occasion to use `partition` for anything. What is it usually used for?

Comment: @matt It mutates an array by reordering its elements, those that match a condition are placed at the end, of the resulting array. It returns an integer, which is the index, in the resulting array, of the first elements that matches the condition passed in the closure `belongsInSecondPartition`

Comment: I know what it does. I can read the documentation. I'm asking you why one would have occasion to do that in real life.

Comment: @matt possible use cases could be: 1) Speed: Quickly split (virtually) arrays based on a condition, without having to go through O(n) twice using *filter*. The return value of *partition* would be the delimiter. 2) Memory efficiency: filtering without creating new arrays.

Comment: @matt I've recently used `partition` [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/207869/49921).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `partition` is returning just index not array like `filter`.
`partition` is reindexing your array based on condition, it will arrange all non-satisfy elements before satisfying elements.
 So, `partition` will return the first index of satisfying element.
The error you were getting for using mutating member for `partition` will be solve like this.

```
func NonZeroArrayWithPartition(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var array = array
//    return array.partition(by: { $0 > 0 }) + array.partition(by: { $0 == 0 }) // your statement
    _ = array.partition(by: {$0 == 0})
    return array
}
```

Your statement is commented cause it will pass `Array.Index` (i.e. index of array) while the dunction should return array if `int`.  While using this approch you can declare like this otherwise you'll get warning.
`let inputArray = [1,4,0,0,5,1,0]`  
Here is another approch for same thing.

```
var inputArray = [1,4,0,0,5,1,0]
...
NonZeroArrayWithPartition(array: &inputArray)
...
func NonZeroArrayWithPartition(array:inout [Int]) -> [Int] {
    _ = array.partition(by: {$0 == 0})
    return array
}
```

It'll change source array (i.e. call by reference)
Here is some statements for you to understand better, the behaviour of `partition`.

```
var inputArray = [1,4,0,0,5,1,0]
print(inputArray)
print(NonZeroArrayWithFilter(array: inputArray))
print(inputArray)
print(NonZeroArrayWithPartition(array: &inputArray))
print(inputArray)
```

output will be like below

> [1, 4, 0, 0, 5, 1, 0]
>   
>   [1, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0]
>   
>   [1, 4, 0, 0, 5, 1, 0]
>   
>   [1, 4, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0]
>   
>   [1, 4, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0]

Here is [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017527-partition&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1540043457409000&usg=AFQjCNFVf-zHQ0gCZngFlIYrEbvOoFZIbw) for `partition`.
Personally, I suggest using `partition` function for this kind of approach.
Because filter function will create 2 arrays and you need to join them, while partition will just reindex the array.

Comment: Partition doesn't work here. Please try with `[0,1,2,0,6,0,2,5,0]`

Comment: Are you using my condition? I've updated condition for partition method . I'm not using your condition.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` makes a new array, and keeps the original intact. `partition(by:)` works on an Array in-place. Either you need to making your array mutable, or you need to make a mutable copy. For example:

```
extension MutableCollection where Self.Element: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral & Equatable {
    mutating func moveZerosToEnd() -> Self {
        var copy = self
        _ = copy.partition(by: { $0 == 0 })
        return copy
    }
}

var inputArray = [1,4,0,0,5,1,0] 

print(inputArray.moveZerosToEnd())
```

Comment: Your example ruins input array : `[0,1,2,0,6,0,2,5,0]` -> `[5,1,2,2,6,0,0,0,0]`

Comment: @PavloBoiko No it doesn't.

Comment: @PavloBoiko The OP did not state that order should be preserved among the nonzero elements, and indeed, his own example does not preserve it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way will create own sort descriptor. Then you no need to twice "walk" through array.

```
let array = [1,2,0,6,0,2,5]
func nonZeroSortDescriptor(lhs: Int, rhs: Int -> Bool {
    return rhs == 0
}
array.sorted(by: nonZeroSortDescriptor)
//1,2,6,2,5,0,0
```

**UPD**

Also, @Alexander was right, сomplexity of this sort will be `O(2N + 1)`, so here optimized way to sort:

```
func NonZeroArrayWithFilterFast(array:[Int]) -> [Int] {
    var zerosCount = 0
    return array.filter({
        if $0 == 0 {
            zerosCount += 1
        }
        return $0 > 0
    }) + [Int](repeating: 0, count: zerosCount)
}
NonZeroArrayWithFilterFast(array: array)
```

Complexity of this algorithm is `O(N)`

Comment: Swift's sort isn't guaranteed to be stable, so this won't necessarily work. Also, it's worse performance than just using partition.

Comment: `nonZeroSortDescriptor` shouldn't throw.

Comment: The update looks very familiar ... but doesn't work